# NSURLSession Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=28 "No space left on device"

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, urlsession

we use single `NSURLSession` download remote image from network.

But we got strange error log that somebody cannot show image because got error `Error`

> Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=28 "No space left on device"

This error happens rarely and cannot reproduce.

And we collect disk usage info and make create file test. We cannot find abnormal phenomena.

When the user met the problem reload again and image can show again.

This is very strange, anyone met the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know why, but you can use SDWebImage download image to fix this error

Comment: For some reasons we have to use a custom NSURLSession. ⊙︿⊙